# How to make only part of div sticky?

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I'm looking to make just a few letters sticky in a paragraph that is otherwise scrollable. I have made a fiddle to illustrate the concept, where ideally all red text scrolls while blue is sticky. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```css
div {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 4.5rem;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;  
    color: blue;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: inherit;
    font-size: 3rem;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>

<div>1 1 1 1 1 1</div>
<div>2 2 2 2 2 2</div>

<div class="sticky">3 3 3 
<span style="color: red">4 4 4</span>
</div> 

<div>5 5 5 5 5 5</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/35qfws0c/2/

Comment: is it for this particular case or there is a more generic case?

Comment: Temani Afif, it is for this particular case, more or less. I have a paragraph of text (4 lines) and would like just one word in the middle of it to be sticky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea that requires a content duplication. The trick is to make two similar lines above each other and you hide elements inside them alternately:

```css
div {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 4.5rem;
  bottom: 1em; /* bigger than 0 since the element is having height=0 */
  text-align: right;
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 999;
  
  height:0; /* this will make them above each other */
}

.sticky > *:not(.main) {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.dupe > .main {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>

<div>1 1 1 1 1 1</div>
<div>2 2 2 2 2 2</div>

<div class="sticky"><span class="main">3 3 3</span> <span>4 4 4</span> </div>
<div class="dupe"><span class="main">3 3 3</span>   <span>4 4 4</span> </div>

<div>5 5 5 5 5 5</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```